# extracting and rewriting csv data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, database, csv

I've got a cvs file that I need to extract the first name, last name, and phone number. The list originated from an email that used delimited data in the following format:

```
Level,Name,Address 1,Address 2,City,State,ZIPcode,Phone,Title,Freq,Next Ship Date,ARO S,ARO ID,Prod,FName
0,"FAUST, A ","6 TYNE DR","","FRANKLIN ",KY,37064 ,309-279-5026,SSC, , , , , ,A FAUST
```

I was able to save as a csv file in excel. I am now trying to use python to extract first name, last name, and phone number then write to a new csv file. So far I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv((r'C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\customers.csv'),encoding= 'unicode_escape')
print (df)
```

Result:

```
     0,"FAUST, A ","6 TYNE DR","","FRANKLIN ",KY,39064 ,309-279-5026,SSC, , , , , ,A FAUST
0    1,"ANDERSON, B ","91 CHAMPIONS CIR","",...                                                 
1    1,"ANDREWS, A ","1474 CANNON ST","","DA...
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [662 rows x 1 columns]   Forgot to add this

Comment: Hi Wade,Stack overflow is not a resource for outsourcing your coding projects. If you have specific questions about particular methods, then feel free to ask them. But you have not even attempted to do anything remotely resembling extracting text from a string or manipulating any of the columns.

Comment: Thank you Lucas for commenting. Perhaps I should have mentioned that I'm totally new to python and programming in general. So I'm asking for help at this stage, this is as far as I have gotten. Otherwise I would have hired a programmer to accomplish this goal. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you create the new Dataframe (and export) with index

just save it without the implicit index

i.e.

```
df.to_excel("./excel.xls", index=False)
```